# How do I disable TextField input with MUI Autocomplete?

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete, textfield

I'm using `Autocomplete` with `TextField` for `renderInput` throughout my app for form field input, but have one case where I don't want to allow any text input and only permit the selection of one of the dropdown elements.

If I switch to the more natural `Select` component, however, the styling of the dropdown elements is different. In particular, the width of the options doesn't seem to be inherited from the `FormControl` element.

If I use Autocomplete and use dev tools in the browser to set the `disabled` property of the `input` element, everything behaves as I would like. But if I pass `inputProps={{disabled: true}}` to `TextField`, things blow up when I click the dropdown.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should rewrite `readOnly` attribute of a native input element to `true` via `inputProps` of `renderInput` to achieve the desired result:

```
    <Autocomplete
      renderInput={({ inputProps, ...rest }) =>    <TextField
      {...rest}
      inputProps={{ ...inputProps, readOnly: true }}
    />
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/disabled-input-ogrjdx?file=/demo.tsx:185-460)

Comment: Appreciated you redirecting me towards `readOnly` rather than `disabled`, but I was surprised that I had to explicitly merge in my inputProps changes. I thought MUI implicitly did a "merge" of any inputProps specified. Is that behavior documented anywhere that you know of?

Comment: I didn't find this behavior to be documented anywhere in documentation but I found in the [example of async autocomplete component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#asynchronous-requests) how they added an extra icon to the `TextField` via `InputProps` and applied the same approach towards rewriting attributes of `inputProps`.

Comment: Yep, for me was a lot of try hard digging until I realise this with the merge... anyways thanks for the `readOnly` sugestion!